# Converting C++ dll injector into unicode

Tags: c++, dll, unicode

Okay so Ive Ran and tested the solution given on the [website](http://snipd.net/dll-injection-in-c), which came with positive results.

Now I've converted this into a win32 unicode project without any compile errors or runtime errors(it even says its injected the dll). Without any noticeable errors everything seems fine other than the fact that the dll is not executing after injection.

Keep in mind the Dll does work if the Injectors character set is not set, but not if converted into unicode. Ive even converted the dll into unicode just to test and that works on the NON unicode Injector. With that in mind ive came to the conclusion that the problem lies in the converted Injector.

If anymore information is needed feel free to ask. You may also ask, why convert into unicode? its my personal preference. Since i did not write the code myself converting does help me learn the code.

I did Erase the 2nd function but that function was never called and was practically useless. it was the same function except with A different Variable Type. Conversion did not work prior to erasing.

Is there anything wrong with this code?
I think the problem is here in Injector.cpp

**Now I am thinking its the DLL. After changing `kernel32.dll` to something random i do receive an error through `GetLastError()` error 127 which was expected. But then the program of which was injected into crashes. which then means the dll was injected. ** So After thinking this through I tested without adding a dll into the equation, throws the same error along with the crash. seems like its injecting but its not injecting the dll. ** `DLL_NAME` is being loaded into the function. `wcslen(DLL_NAME)` is returning a value, along with `RemoteString`(is 0 with no dll loaded).
That being said I've included Dllmain.cpp

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
wchar_t* helloStr;
wchar_t buf[250];

switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    helloStr = L"Hello";
    wsprintf(buf, helloStr);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buf, NULL, NULL);
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    helloStr = L"Goodbye";
    wsprintf(buf, helloStr);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buf, NULL, NULL);
    break;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Injector.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include "Resource.h"


Injector::Injector(void)
{
}


Injector::~Injector(void)
{
}

#define CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS (PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ) 

bool Injector::Inject(wchar_t* procName, wchar_t* DLL_NAME)
{
    DWORD pID = GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName(procName);


    HANDLE Proc = 0;
    HMODULE hLib = 0;
    wchar_t buf[50] = { 0 };
    LPVOID RemoteString, LoadLibAddy;

    if (!pID)
        return false;

    Proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);

    if (!Proc)
    {
        swprintf_s(buf, L"OpenProcess() failed: %d", GetLastError());
        MessageBoxW(NULL, buf, L"Loader", MB_OK);
        wprintf(buf);
        return false;
    }

    LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");

    // Allocate space in the process for our DLL 
    RemoteString = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(Proc, NULL, wcslen(DLL_NAME), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // Write the string name of our DLL in the memory allocated 
    WriteProcessMemory(Proc, (LPVOID)RemoteString, DLL_NAME, wcslen(DLL_NAME), NULL);

    // Load our DLL 
    CreateRemoteThread(Proc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddy, (LPVOID)RemoteString, NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(Proc);
    return true;
}



DWORD Injector::GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName(wchar_t* ProcName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    HANDLE thSnapShot;
    BOOL retval = false;

    thSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (thSnapShot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error: Unable to create toolhelp snapshot!", L"2MLoader", MB_OK);

        return false;
    }

    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    retval = Process32First(thSnapShot, &pe);
    while (retval)
    {
        if (!wcscmp(pe.szExeFile, ProcName))
        {
            return pe.th32ProcessID;
        }
        retval = Process32Next(thSnapShot, &pe);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Resource.h

```
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

#define _APS_NO_MFC                 130
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE    129
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE     32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE     1000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE       110
#endif
#endif
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

class Injector
{
public:
    Injector(void);
    ~Injector(void);

    bool Inject(wchar_t* procName, wchar_t* DLL_NAME);


private:
    DWORD GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName(wchar_t * ProcName);
};
```

Main.cpp

```
// DLL_Injector_WIN32.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DLL_Injector_WIN32.h"
#include <Commdlg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Resource.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
Injector* injector = new Injector();
// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
wchar_t szFile[MAX_PATH];
LPTSTR PROC_NAME = new TCHAR[1024];

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL                FileOpen(HWND hwnd);
int                 start(wchar_t* DLL_PATH, wchar_t* PROC_NAME);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_DLL_INJECTOR_WIN32, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_DLL_INJECTOR_WIN32));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_DLL_INJECTOR_WIN32));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_DLL_INJECTOR_WIN32);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable


      hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
       WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
       szWindowClass,
       szTitle,
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
       CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 350, 100,
       NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            L"BUTTON",
            L"Inject",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            280, 10, 45, 25,
            hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_INJECT, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
        CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            L"BUTTON",
            L"DLL",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            240, 10, 35, 25,
            hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_DLL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
        CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            L"EDIT",
            L"",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            65, 10, 170, 25,
            hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_PROCESS, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
        CreateWindowEx(
            0,
            L"STATIC",
            L"Process",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            5, 10, 55, 25,
            hWnd, (HMENU)NULL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDC_DLL:
        {
            FileOpen(hWnd);
//          MessageBox(NULL, szFile, L"TEST", NULL);
        }
        break;
        case IDC_INJECT:
        {
            GetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_PROCESS, PROC_NAME, 1024);

            start(szFile, PROC_NAME);
        }
        break;
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
BOOL FileOpen(HWND hwnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;

    HANDLE hf;


    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;


    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"DLL\0*.dll\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;




    if (GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn) == TRUE)
    {
        //CheckDlgButton(hwnd, IDC_PASS_LIST, BST_UNCHECKED);

        hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            (HANDLE)NULL);
        return TRUE;
        if (hf == (HANDLE)-1)
        {

            MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not open this file", L"File I/O Error", MB_ICONSTOP);
            return FALSE;
        }




    }
    else
    {

        return FALSE;
    }
}
int start(wchar_t* DLL_PATH, wchar_t* PROC_NAME)
{


    WCHAR dllDir[MAX_PATH];

    wcscpy_s(dllDir, MAX_PATH, DLL_PATH);

    //MessageBox(NULL, dllDir, L"DLL path: ", MB_ICONSTOP);
    //MessageBox(NULL, PROC_NAME, L"Process: ", MB_ICONSTOP);

    if (injector->Inject(PROC_NAME, dllDir)){

        MessageBox(NULL, L"DLL injected!", L"DLL injected!", MB_ICONSTOP);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to inject the dll...", L"File I/O Error", MB_ICONSTOP);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add checks after the various Windows API calls to determine what works and what fails and use GetLastError() to see the error code, if any.  The `GetProcAddress()` looks like there may be an error in the parameters.

Comment: @RichardChambers I was Thinking the same thing since there is not a Unicode equivalent.  
so i through this  'swprintf_s(buf, L"Test 6: %d", GetLastError());
 MessageBoxW(NULL, buf, L"Loader", MB_OK);'
around with different test numbers and no errors were called in any location. As in The message was 0

Comment: @MikeJones: I think what Richard was referring was that you obtain the address of `LoadLibraryA`, yet you (later) pass it a wide string DLL name.

Comment: @MikeJones: Use LoadLibraryW instead. Since the code has worked (with ANSI strings) I assume that passing a this-process address of thread start proc is OK, or otherwise that I'm misunderstanding what's going on. It's a bit late in the morning here. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf When you said LoadLibraryA i thought you meant the variable which was created (LoadLibAddy). simple misunderstanding. Ive changed it to ~LoadLIbraryW still the same results and No GetLastError() code.

Comment: @RichardChambers any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `WriteProcessMemory` wanted `DLL_NAME` to be a `char`. converted `wchar_t*` to `char`  in a new `variable` and now i have no problems.